# Why does this regex prefix not work?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got a sample data I'm looking to find matches within. I'm testing in Notepad++.

```
QA 44
ABQ DAL 280
ABQ HOU 290
HOU PHX 210
DAL PHX 102
```

When I use the following regular expression, I get matches as expected on the last four lines

```
([A-Z]{3}\s){2}[0-9]{3}
```

But when I try to hone in on the 3-digit number at the end and move everything else to a prefix, no matches come back.

```
(?<=([A-Z]{3}\s){2})[0-9]{3}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong with the prefix? I want all those 3-digit numbers to match and qualify on the letter codes before it, but it is not working.

Comment: What's your use case? Any reason you can't use capture groups (i.e., with the first regex)?

Comment: notepad++ uses `perl` based RegEx, which only supports literal/fixed-length strings in lookbehinds.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

 and 

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookbehind

Comment: I did not know that about notepad++. Maybe it is not the best regex testing tool for prefix/suffix stuff then. But these are fully supported in Java right because that is what I am targeting...

Comment: not sure off the top of my head, I'd be surprised if it's not supported in java - have a look at http://regex101.com you can try different engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the last digits you need a none-capture group within look behind :

```
(?<=(?:[A-Z]{3}\s){2})[0-9]{3}
```

[see demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT9pU7/1)

Comment: None-capture groups did cross my mind. Don't know why I didn't try that. Thanks!

Comment: But it is a fixed length regex! I'd have to test to make sure but I think boost accepts this as OP expected.

Comment: @Jongware Yeah exactly its a fixed length! I don't know where this mistake exactly come from?? :) thanks for noting that!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't use a look behind with an anchor?

```
(?<=\s)\d{3}$
```

Comment: That is very valid for this simplified SSCCE I put together, but for my real business problem I need to use a prefix.